# Log4j error java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.log4j.bridge.LogEventAdapter overrides final method getTimeStamp.()J

Tags: spring, log4j, log4j2, apache-commons-logging, apache-ranger

while running my webapplication I am getting below log4j error.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.log4j.bridge.LogEventAdapter overrides final method getTimeStamp.()J
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
at org.apache.log4j.builders.BuilderManager.<clinit>(BuilderManager.java:58)
at org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1Configuration.<init>(Log4j1Configuration.java:46)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:90)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:58)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:499)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:404)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:318)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:690)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
```

Seems this is due to multiple versions of log4j, but which version is causing problem I am not able to check that.

Adding log4j related jars that I have in my classpath

```
/ews/lib/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar
/ews/lib/log4j-core-2.20.0.jar
/ews/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
/ews/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.20.0.jar
/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.2.10.jar
/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.20.0.jar
/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4jdbc-1.2.jar
/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.20.0.jar
/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
/ews/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2-api-2.20.0.jar
/cred/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

Full stack trace

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.log4j.bridge.LogEventAdapter overrides final method getTimeStamp.()J
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.log4j.builders.BuilderManager.<clinit>(BuilderManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1Configuration.<init>(Log4j1Configuration.java:46)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:499)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:404)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:318)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:690)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.apache.ranger.server.tomcat.EmbeddedServer.startServer(EmbeddedServer.java:380)
    at org.apache.ranger.server.tomcat.EmbeddedServer.start(EmbeddedServer.java:331)
    at org.apache.ranger.server.tomcat.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:113)

Jan 31, 2024 11:16:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jan 31, 2024 11:16:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 31, 2024 11:16:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 31, 2024 11:16:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.<clinit>(ContextCleanupListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:923)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at org.apache.ranger.server.tomcat.EmbeddedServer.startServer(EmbeddedServer.java:380)
    at org.apache.ranger.server.tomcat.EmbeddedServer.start(EmbeddedServer.java:331)
    at org.apache.ranger.server.tomcat.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Exception java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.log4j.bridge.LogEventAdapter overrides final method getTimeStamp.()J [in thread "main"]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2470)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    at org.apache.log4j.builders.BuilderManager.<clinit>(BuilderManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.Log4j1Configuration.<init>(Log4j1Configuration.java:46)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfiguration.<init>(PropertiesConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:499)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:404)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:318)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:690)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
```

Comment: Do you really need so much different logging frameworks?

Comment: This is a big project consisting of multiple separate components and parent has all the dependencies.

Comment: You must also have **another** replacement of `log4j:log4j` on your classpath. Look for `reload4j`, `log4j-over-slf4j`, `apache-logging-extras` or similar.

Comment: yes reload4j was causing this issue.

Comment: Can you add an answer with the list of Log4j 1.2 clones you looked for?